# Get data from the model class in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a DetailView of a specific channel. All the data of the channel is listed here. There is a model class named 'ExecutionLog'. Currently, all others data are shown in the detail view except the data from the 'ExecutionLog' model class.

The class is in 'Class-based views' which is totally new to me. I could not understand what is really going on.

DetailView class view:

```
class ChannelDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, SuperAdminMixin, ChannelView, DetailView):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ChannelDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        if 'date' in self.request.GET:
            d = self.request.GET['date']
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        else:
            date = datetime.date.today()
        context['activePage'] = {'tree': 'ChannelPage', 'branch': 'index'}
        datas = get_datas_hourly(True, self.object.id, date)
        matches_data = get_datas_hourly(False,self.object.id, date)
        context['date'] = date
        context['labels'] = datas.keys()
        context['values'] = datas.values()
        context['matches_labels'] = matches_data.keys()
        context['matches_values'] = matches_data.values()
        return context
```

model for ExecutionLog:

```
class ExecutionLog(models.Model):
    ACTION_TYPES = (
        (0, 'START'),
        (1, 'STOP'),
        (2, 'ASSIGNED'),
        (3, 'ERROR'),
        (4, 'OTHERS'),
    )
    type = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=ACTION_TYPES)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    execution = models.ForeignKey(Execution, related_name="execution_logs")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

I want to get the ExecutionLog data of the specific channel the detailview page is of.

Comment: So, what is actually your problem? what error are you getting?

Comment: I did not understand how to actually the get data from the model class and send it through the  'ChannelDetailView' class.

Comment: did you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/  ?

Comment: Thanks @BearBrown the doc was helpful. Finally know what really is going on. But what I still don't understand is how to get the values from 'ExecutionLog' to the view class

Comment: do you need to create ExecutionLogView or you need add ExecutionLog to the ChannelDetailView

Comment: I need to get the data from the ExecutionLog in the ChannelDetailView so that I can display the value in my html file. I dont know if I need to add ExecutionLog to the ChannelDetailView inorder to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to override your `get()` method,

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
    return self.render_to_response(context)
```

You could edit the view as your requirements. Also, take a look at the definition of [DetailView](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/) before anything.

**EDIT**:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(ChannelDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

    if 'date' in self.request.GET:
        d = self.request.GET['date']
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
    else:
        date = datetime.date.today()
    context['activePage'] = {'tree': 'ChannelPage', 'branch': 'index'}
    datas = get_datas_hourly(True, self.object.id, date)
    matches_data = get_datas_hourly(False,self.object.id, date)
    context['date'] = date
    context['labels'] = datas.keys()
    context['values'] = datas.values()
    context['matches_labels'] = matches_data.keys()
    context['matches_values'] = matches_data.values()
    context['executionLogs'] = ExecutionLog.objects.all()
    #^^^^^^^^^^^ You can access the execution logs in your template.
    return context
```

You have to iterate through the queryset and access the attributes one by one in the template, like

```
{% for item in execution_log %} 
    {{ item.type }} 
    {{ item.title }}
    {{ item.description }}
    .....
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I just want to get the 'ExecutionLog' data here in the view class. Should I do this. Every other thing are working just fine

Comment: The view in your question, is it all or are there anything more in the view??

Comment: There are other views. But for 'ChannelDetailView' this is the only one

Comment: What I meant was, in the view you just posted, there is only one method `get_context_data()`.. Are there any other methods defined in your code?? If not, you definitely need to add a `get()` method.

Comment: No, `get_context_data()` is the only one. Can't I just write the query to get ExecutionLog data in the same function and return the values?

Comment: Yes, you could then write the query in the `get_context_data()` itself and pass it in the context and render in the template.

Comment: I wrote the query `execution_log = ExecutionLog.objects.all()[:1].get()` but this gives me `<ExecutionLog: ExecutionLog object>` which is not what I wanted

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: I have done the same thing as I have stated in above comment. The result I get is `<ExecutionLog: ExecutionLog object>`. It doesnot gives me the field and its value in the execution log.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks man. It worked. I understood what was going on. Again, thank you